# Find element height, including margin

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a simple and fun drawing app, and in it the structure is as follows:

- Header
- Canvas
- Footer

I'm trying to get the canvas to be the full height of the window, minus the header height and footer height.

I've tried multiple things like:

```
canvas.height = window.height - (document.getElementById("header").offsetHeight + document.getElementById("footer").offsetHeight);
```

And I've even tried:

```
function getHeight(id) {
    id = document.getElementById(id);
    return id.offsetHeight + id.style.marginTop + id.style.marginBottom;
}

canvas.height = window.height - (getHeight("header") + getHeight("footer"))
```

But to no avail. In the console `id.style.marginTop` just returned an empty string, although its marginTop is set in the css... just not set specifically to marginTop, it's set as `margin: 8px 0 8px 0;`

**Is there any way, without using jQuery, to obtain the rendered height of an element, including margin?**

I'm assuming we'd have to separate the `margin: 8px 0 8px 0;` into separate variables, using `id.style.margin`... but I'm just not sure how to separate it.

Comment: did you remember to replace "id" in the parentheses with the actual element's ID? Surely you don't have an id named "id"?

Comment: @TylerH I've edited the question to compensate for the confusion I caused.

Comment: For me personally, I create my header as a separate file and create an outer-wrapper in it, but don't close the div. Then you create your canvas page, and close out the outer-wrapper at the bottom before you include your footer file. Then the canvas will be the exact size between your header and footer. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Fata1Err0r I'm having some trouble visualizing what you're saying.

Comment: @Elegant.Scripting I create a header file, my main page, and my footer file. In my header, I create a DIV wrapper that's going to wrap both my header/main contents together, but I don't close the DIV yet. On my main page, leave out the normal initial HTML tags (<head> <body> etc...) and at the bottom you put your </div> to close the DIV wrapper from the header, and then use PHP to include the footer file at the bottom. You'll use PHP to include the header at the top of the main page too. This keeps main page exact size of the space between the header/footer.

Comment: I'm at work so I don't have time to show you the code itself. I get off in 20 mins and will type it up when I get home for you. It's a similar approach as Rick, but not the exact same. It's also useful for when you have multiple pages and you want the keep the same header/footer in place. I'll reach out to you in an hour or so, and can show you hands-on what I mean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
function outerWidth(el) {
  var width = el.offsetWidth;
  var style = getComputedStyle(el);

  width += parseInt(style.marginLeft) + parseInt(style.marginRight);
  return width;
}
```

this does exactly what jquery's outerwidth is doing, scratched from ::http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/
might be interteresting for further develpoment

**EDIT**: in ie8 you have to use el.currentStyle[prop] instead of getComputedStyle(el);

Comment: The example works perfectly, and you gave me an awesome resource as well, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You could use a flex solution and not worry about calculating the height:

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

canvas {
  flex: 1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <header>...</header>
  <canvas>...</canvas>
  <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m4d3tgxg/)

Comment: This is what I was speaking about in my comment to you. Use wrappers and separate the sections like this. It'll give you the desired result, and you don't have to mess with the actual calculations.

Comment: Does this distort the canvas resolution?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but let me know if it does.

Comment: It shouldn't distort it. It's going to base it upon the browser/monitor, just as it would if you manually did it how you're trying to.

Comment: I just tested this, and although it's a simple and beautiful solution, it does distort the canvas and has limited browser support. I do think this styling method would be fantastic for web design excluding the dimensions of a canvas though.

Comment: What's the exact dimensions you need the canvas to be?? There may be an entirely different solution to this problem since users can always change the size of their browser window. I can thin of a few ways that you could make it fixed, but if they shrink their window, it wouldn't display all of it, though it would retain the actual size of the canvas itself.

Comment: @Fata1Err0r With JavaScript, on window resize, I've made the canvas update its dimensions and ratio. It's really dynamic now. I'll give you an explanation of why you should always do it with HTML (for fixed dimensions) or JavaScript (for dynamic dimensions), not CSS.

Comment: @Fata1Err0r The reason the canvas size has to be set with HTML or JavaScript is because setting it with CSS will only change the dimensions of the canvas, not the ratio at which the canvas displays things. The HTML or JavaScript width and height attributes of the canvas element define the ratio, and the CSS will in turn set its width and height properties to match those attributes. To set the canvas size with CSS alone would be kind of like taking an image at its original size, and scaling it to a different size; the newly displayed image would be distorted, even though its dimensions changed.