# HTML element height including margin and children's margin

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can get the height of an element with

```
HTMLElement.offsetHeight
```

but this is without margin. I can get the height including margin using the function from [Find element height, including margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547940/find-element-height-including-margin).

But if I have a child element with a bigger margin than parent that function does not give me the height I want. How to I get the height of an element including margin of both the element and child elements?

**Related example:**

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <p>
      New York
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#inner {
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}

#inner p {
  margin-top: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

If I use **outer.offsetHeight** the height is including the margin of the p-element. But if I remove the 1px padding of inner, then **outer.offsetHeight** disregards the margin of the p-element. Why?

Comment: I get "Uncaught TypeError: outer.offsetHeight is not a function" error. Can you please provide a fiddle ? You can try giving overflow: hidden to outer div and check if that works.

Comment: Sure, offsetHeight is not a function. By bad. Have corrected it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for that is ["margin collapsing"](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins). Basically, it combines the two margins of your blocks into one. In your case it only occurs if there is no padding.

The specification is a bit hard to read in my opinion, so you probably find [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) easier!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Then I need the padding or a transparent border to be able to get the full height. Good to know.

Comment: If you want something invisible you could also set `overflow:auto`, which creates a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context).

Comment: But that adds scrollbars when needed

Comment: Yes! If there is scrollable overflow. Sometimes you can avoid that (e.g. by setting heights on the elements inside rather than on the container itself), however it gets more tricky with transforms.

Answer (score 2):

Change the *#inner* display to **flex**:

```
#inner {
  display: flex;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/charlesartbr/gs3orv59/12/

Comment: But display: flex has other implications too. But it seems to work.

Comment: This works because it prevents the margins from collapsing as the answer marked correct suggests.