# How to get full height (including margins) with window.getComputedStyle()?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, styles

I am trying to get the full height of a `JSX element` in `ReactJS` using `window.getComputedStyle`, however I'd like to get the full value, `height+margin`, but I couldn't find a way.

When I use only height I don't get the margin value.

`window.getComputedStyle(productsContainerRef.current).height`

I know I can get both values separetely and sum them, but is there a straightforward way to do that?

I am getting the element using a `ref`, so, it wouldn't be possible to use the event to aim the target element and get `outerHeight`.

Is there a way to do that using getComputedStyle?

Comment: Here is the answer I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29548116/210342

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add the margins to the refs current height.

Example:

```
  const outerHeight = (el) => {
    var height = el.offsetHeight;
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    height += parseInt(style.marginTop) + parseInt(style.marginBottom);
    return height;
  };
```